# Chart.JS Display 5 largest values in the legend

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I was wondering how to go about using Chart.JS to limit the amount of items displayed in the legend. I'd like to set essentially a max amount of 5, and it'll display the 5 largest values in the legend. I'm assuming this would be done with a filter function in the options.plugins.labels, but I'm not sure how to go about checking the datasets against each other and then only displaying the 5 largest.

Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the entire data field of the object as second argument, so you can calculate the amount each dataset represents and then check if it is that dataset:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [120, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points1',
        data: [17, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points2',
        data: [27, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points3',
        data: [37, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points4',
        data: [47, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points5',
        data: [57, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points6',
        data: [67, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points7',
        data: [77, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points8',
        data: [87, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points9',
        data: [97, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          filter: (ds, data) => {
            const sortable = [];

            data.datasets.forEach(d => {
              sortable.push([d.label, d.data.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0)])
            });

            sortable.sort((a, b) => (b[1] - a[1]));
            const sorted = sortable.slice(0, 5).map(e => (e[0]));

            return sorted.includes(ds.text)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't think about doing it this way, thanks so much again