# chartjs top 5 legend doughtnut

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've found a beautiful example to get the top 5 for a line graph in the legend in chartjs.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71426252/chart-js-display-5-largest-values-in-the-legend)
unfortunaly I have to deal whit a doughnutchart and can't figure it out how to convert this piece of code to do this. javascript is not mine "goto"-code language and am a little stuck.
Could somebody help me do the same "top 5 biggest" as legend or doughnut charts?

```
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [120, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points1',
        data: [17, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points2',
        data: [27, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points3',
        data: [37, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points4',
        data: [47, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points5',
        data: [57, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points6',
        data: [67, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points7',
        data: [77, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points8',
        data: [87, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points9',
        data: [97, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          filter: (ds, data) => {
            const sortable = [];

            data.datasets.forEach(d => {
              sortable.push([d.label, d.data.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0)])
            });

            sortable.sort((a, b) => (b[1] - a[1]));
            const sorted = sortable.slice(0, 5).map(e => (e[0]));

            return sorted.includes(ds.text)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe you could find something helpful here: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/10317

Comment: got it working , thnx.......

Answer (score 0):

for futhere poeple and thnx to @user2057925 and some fiddeling got it working :
($theme_dark is a variable to change the colors from php)

```
        <script>
          const ass_data_dou = <?php echo json_encode(array_column($assarr, 'total_all')); ?>;
          const ass_labels_dou = <?php echo json_encode(array_column($assarr, 'name')); ?>;
          const pieGenerateLabelsLegendHandler = Chart.controllers.doughnut.overrides.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels;
          const pieLegendClickHandler = Chart.controllers.doughnut.overrides.plugins.legend.onClick;
          let others = [];
          var theme_dark = <?php echo json_encode($theme_dark); ?>;
          let color1 = "#666666"
          let color2 = "red"
          if (theme_dark) {
            color1 = "#CCCCCC"
            color2 = "blue"
          }
          const data_custom_dou = {
            labels: ass_labels_dou,
            datasets: [{
              data: ass_data_dou,
              backgroundColor: ['#3366cc',
                                '#dc3912',
                                '#ff9900',
                                '#109618',
                                '#990099',
                                '#0099c6',
                                '#dd4477',
                                '#66aa00',
                                '#b82e2e',
                                '#316395',
                                '#994499',
                                '#22aa99']
            }],
          };
          const optionsCustom_dou = {
            plugins: {
              title: {
                display: true,
                position: "top",
                text: "legend tit",
                color: color1,
                padding: {
                  top: 5,
                  bottom: 0
                },
                font: {
                  size: 20
                }
              },
              legend: {
                position: "right",
                labels: {
                  color: color1,
                  font: {
                    size: 20
                  },
                  generateLabels(chart) {
                    const labels = pieGenerateLabelsLegendHandler(chart);
                    const sorted = labels.sort((a, b) => chart.data.datasets[0].data[a.index] <= chart.data.datasets[0].data[b.index]);
                    const top5 = sorted.filter((el, index) => index <= 5);
                    others = sorted.filter((el, index) => index > 5);
                    top5.push({text: 'Others', hidden: others[0].hidden});
                    return top5;
                  }
                },
                onClick(e, legendItem, legend) {
                  if (legendItem.text === 'Others'){
                    const ci = legend.chart;
                    others.forEach(function(item) {
                       ci.toggleDataVisibility(item.index);
                    });
                    ci.update();
                    return;
                  }
                  pieLegendClickHandler(e, legendItem, legend);
                }
              }
            }
          };
          const chart_dou = new Chart("chart_dou_distrubution", {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: data_custom_dou,
            options: optionsCustom_dou
          });
        </script>
```